# Does a UK-resident Pakistani need a visa for Dubai?

Tags: visas, pakistani-citizens, dubai, uae, uk-residents

My nationality is Pakistani, but I’m living in the UK. I have a British resident card but not a British passport. I’m travelling in December to Dubai. Do I need apply for a tourist visa?